# how can i update state to assign the value of readAsDataURL.result?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using useState() hook how can I update my state I want to assign readAsDataURL.result so I can upload a file?

```
const uploadFile = event => {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  let file = event.target.files[0];
  console.log(file); //I can see the file's info

  reader.onload = event => {
    console.log("event", event.target.result);

    setSelectedFile(event.target.result); //its giving me null here how can i update state?
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  console.log("State", selectedFile);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To update state all you need is to call the correspponding state function.

This is to create state.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

Here count is your variable and setCount corresponding state function.

```
setCount(1);
```

When you call this function `count` value will change to `1`. This way you can also update any state that you define.

In your code you didn't show your state code. So try putting that by editing your question.

**EDIT**

In react useState hook is used to set a state which can be any value `number`, `list`, `object` etc. useState returns a state variable and a corresponding function to update that state and this corresponding function is an asynchronous function and did not update state right away. To check if the state has been updated an another hook is required called `useEffect`. useState hook will run whenever state is changed.

So for an example, to see if `selectedFile` state has been changed we can use below code to run whenever selectedFile state is changed and then console.log the value of state `selectedFile`:

```
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(selectedFile);
}, [selectedFile]);
```

Comment: const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null); i have defiend it in my code like this but im geting null when i update setSelectedFile(event.target.result); on reader.onload function

Comment: `setSelectedFile` is an async function so try using react hook `useEffect`, i have edited my question and put an example for you to see. Check that.

Comment: Hi @code0x00 please edit your answer to better reflect the purpose of the "EDIT" part and how it helps the question asker so when new users see your answer they would find it easy to be assisted quickly

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: @MansoorIshaq if this answers your question then please accept this as an answer.

Comment: @NoamYizraeli just added more info to describe my answer.